# Disable an element/class/id from append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way where in I can disabled a certain element/class/id to be appended?

```
<div class="someHtmlElementHereWillAppendOnPageLoad">
   -- but it dont want this part to be appended --
</div>
```

Comment: Please read and apply the following instructions [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) ! If you improve your question, you improve your chances for us to help you!

Comment: There is a code snippet, actually, but it is still absolutely unclear what the OP wants. Show "what is appended" and "what I want to be appended" in a reproducible sample.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: I'm very sorry. I'm new in terms of posting questions here..

I will read the instructions and will post better questions in the future

Comment: what is append is comes from ajax response and the append script far away from where I can edit.

I dont want the certain element to be appaned because I will put my customized elements there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure -- add the attribute `canAppend="no"` to an element then use the attribute selector like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  /* add the attribute selector [canAppend!="no"]  to your select or */
  $("div[canAppend!='no']").append(" appended content here");
});
```

```css
div { border: 2px solid black }
```

```html
<!-- regular divs that dont have the noAppend attribute -->

<div>div 1</div>

<div> div 2</div>

<!-- special div that has the noAppend attribute -->

<div canAppend='no'>div 3 no append </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### EDIT

Since you dont know when the append operation will take place, just do this:

use jQuery to grab all of the values of for divs with a certain class and store those values into an atttribute by using `encodeURIComponent()` and `$("").attr()`

THen make a timer that constantly replaces the div's HTML with the desired HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".someHtmlElementHereWillAppendOnPageLoad").each(function(i, ele) {
    $(ele).attr("lockedContents", encodeURI($(ele).html()))
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    $(".someHtmlElementHereWillAppendOnPageLoad").each(function(i, ele) {
      $(ele).html(decodeURIComponent($(ele).attr("lockedContents")));
    })
  }, 100);

});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="someotherdiv">#1 dont care if it gets edited</div>
<br>

<div class="someHtmlElementHereWillAppendOnPageLoad">
  -- but it dont want this part to be appended --
</div>

<br>
<button value="append to all divs" onclick="$('div').append(' appended text ');">Append to all divs </button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.

however I have no control over the script that appended on the element.

I am working on a Template Editor were In I modify some elements in the template.

the the default setup was  there is a content appended on the element.

I can do this <div canAppend='no'>div 3 no append </div>
but I can do the
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[canAppend!='no']").append(" appended content here");
});

Comment: just make your own little function to do replace the content over and over using a timer (see EDIT)

Comment: thanks you very much @mike510a